# What's the best way to concat my multiple columns into datetime, when I have mixed data in columns, like both varchar and Integer?

Tags: mysql, datetime

So data is a table with the date and time info split into 4 columns, some varchar, others integer:

```
Year   Month   Day   Time
2022   May     20    18:43
1982   Feb     01    00:23
1942   Jan     13    16:17
```

Month and time are varchar, and year and day are integer.

I have to query via MYSQL to find certain dates, and it would be easier if the field I search was datetime like '2022-05-20 18:43'

I have searched all day yesterday and find a lot of examples that come close to what I need but not fit exactly, and I'm not good enough with MYSQL to figure this out.

I assume I have to concat() at some point, but then there is the CONVERSIONS I have to make on the varchar's

I want to run a query that creates a NEW COLUMN in the DB which is datetime and then I can just query straightforward. So create a new column called 'date2' which is datetime, which I already created, just have to concat somehow and then move each rows data to it. Like this:

```
Year   Month   Day   Time    Date2
2022   May     20    18:43   2022-05-20 18:43
1982   Feb     01    00:23   1982-02-01 00:23
1942   Jan     13    16:17   1942-01013 16:17
```

Here is the Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `lunar2` (
  `year` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `month` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `day` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `sign` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `other` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is the code that worked. I thank the person who provided the code:

```
UPDATE table1 SET
other =  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ', Year, Month, Day, Time), '%Y %M %d %H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `STR_TO_DATE()` to create a `DATETIME` value.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD COLUMN Date2 DATETIME;

UPDATE yourTable SET
    Date2 = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ', Year, Month, Day, Time), '%Y %b %d %H:%i:%s');
```

UPDATE: Since your `Time` field is actually of type `TIME`, then we need to use `%H:%i:%s` to correctly parse it.

Comment: I Got a runtime error of: "Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '1800 Jan 1 22:20:00'"  Seems like you did into see that my columns are in varchar and int, and it seems the varchar needs to be converted first, and your code does not do this.

Comment: I updated comment to show the table schema.

Comment: Ok, the formatting issue was you didn't have the seconds formatting of %s. Once I had it, this code worked:   UPDATE lunar2 SET
other =  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ', Year, Month, Day, Time), '%Y %M %d %H:%i:%s');

Comment: Please update your code with correct formatting, when you can.

Comment: `CONCAT` (or `CONCAT_WS`) will combine everything and convert it all into a string.  It's actually the `INT` that needs to be converted first, not the `VARCHAR`.  Everything gets converted into a string.  Your example didn't originally show that the `Time` field had the seconds in it, that's why the `%s` wasn't added.  The final conversion is being done by `STR_TO_DATE`, that converts the "Jan" to the month value (as well as the other values).

Comment: My time field actually does not include seconds, but when formatting, the %s is, seconds, is required. I have no idea why, as I did not require it in the NEW column, but without seconds it just gives a MYSQL error. I assume inserting a datetime ALWAYS adds the seconds(00) by default? Anyway, I can live with seconds added :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you are trying to do.
When converting string to date it is important to get the format string right, otherwise we get a null value.

> ```
> create table datess(
> y int,
> m varchar(3),   
> d int,
> t varchar(5));
> insert into datess (y,m,d,t)values
> (2022 ,'May',  20    ,'18:43'),
> (1982 ,'Feb',  01    ,'00:23'),
> (1942 ,'Jan',  13    ,'16:17');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   STR_TO_DATE(
>   CONCAT(y,'-',m,'-',d,' ',t),
>   '%Y-%M-%d %H:%i') date_format
> FROM datess;
> ```
>
> ```
> | date_format         |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2022-05-20 18:43:00 |
> | 1982-02-01 00:23:00 |
> | 1942-01-13 16:17:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ee654a74cd505f5dace793d08268fb3)*

Comment: The only problem with this answer is that it does not update the table and save the data in a new column, as was my original question. It returns the formatted date, but its not stored in each row under "Date2". I'm gonna play with it to see if I can figure out how to do this though. Thanks anyway.